# Can PhpStorm debug a file that has been redirected to using Nginx's X-Accel-Redirect?

Tags: debugging, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug, x-accel-redirect

I'm using Nginx's X-Accel-Redirect to serve a file **(redirected.php)** that is outside of the webroot. The webroot is `/usr/share/nginx/html` and the file I am wanting to debug is being served from `/usr/share/nginx/downloads`

I begin Xdebug in the browser (debugging works at this stage). At some point the browser makes a request for `website1.com/learning/downloads/url`,
Nginx redirects the request to **redirected.php** using the below rule

```
# Enable X-Accel-Redirect
location /learning/downloads/ {
root /usr/share/nginx/downloads;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /redirected.php last;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't get redirected.php to pause on any breakpoints.

**Is it not possible to debug when using X-Accel-Redirect with PhpStorm? or is it more likely to be a mapping issue?** Suggestions on how to overcome this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: As long as when executing that `redirected.php` script Xdebug is present and enabled there (sees "debug me" flag or configured to try to debug every single request), it will try to debug it (connect to IDE). So first thing you need to confirm that (enable xdebug logging and check generated log file -- does it tries to connect to IDE when hitting that URL?) If it connect but does not debug, then it will be a path mapping issue as your path is clearly outside of the project ( I assume that project root is mapped to `/usr/share/nginx/html`)

Comment: 1) Xdebug can debug any PHP file as long as it is enabled and told to debug it (e.g. cookie or some another way (debug all config value or explicit "debug me" instruction in PHP code). 2) PhpStorm can work with Xdebug as long as it has access to that file and can map the paths. 3) So check debugging attempt first and then describe your project setup/config better (is that all local or remote debug etc etc).

Comment: @LazyOne I got it working thanks to your help. It seems my last config change was actually working, but I hadn't been requesting the correct url (the requested url depends on a few factors ). If you post your comments as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Please post your own answer (and then accept it) with all the details/steps that you did. You know more details and nuances about your case than me (I just gave general info/common logic).

Comment: OK.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a mapping issue. Part of the problem was due to redirected.php being in a folder outside the webroot.

To fix it, I went to File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers and configured it as in the picture below.

[image: Phpstorm Config for debugging files outside webroot]

I also added `xdebug_break();` to the code in redirected.php